# jQuery ToggleClass Is Toggling When I Click On Inside Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have links inside a list item that toggles on click, but when I click on the link the toggleclass activates and it disappears.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content-list > li").live("click", function () {
        $(this).find('.links').toggleClass("hide");
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davemj88/DtrDw/1/

If you click on any link inside the list item it toggles and goes away. I want it to remain visible unless you click on the background or not a link.

I want the list item to toggle UNLESS a user clicks on a link somewhere inside, then I DON'T want it to toggle the class. How do I restrict the toggleclass to only working when a user doesn't click on another link inside?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a click event handler for the links within the li, you can use e.stopPropagation() to prevent that event from bubbling up into the containing li.

```
$(".content-list > li a").live("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPUhs/)

You'll notice though that the delete link isn't affected because the selector used for the event binding is direct descendant li and an anchor tag within that, so you'll want to adjust your selector appropriately, but that should get the idea across.